# How do you store the mutated state, event driven programming?

Tags: events, event-handling, domain-driven-design, data-modeling, cqrs

I have the following case which I am scratching my head. I have an Aggregate lets call it Reservation and I have an Event. Some of the events will lead to the state of the aggregate to be mutated. Some of this state is functional and it naturaly belongs to the aggregate - like "calculated tax" for example. Some of the state I would say is more technical than functional, like if a message is sent to third party system lets call it "isMessageSentToASystem".  In the database I have two tables one for the aggregate one for the event. I see two optioons to preserve the state:

1)I can keep only what has changed in a third table bound to the event. This way I will effectivly recieve a revision log. I don't think this fits well my application though. It will keep my aggregate immutable

2) I will accept that my aggregate is mutable and I will write all functional important state into it ilke "calculatedTax". But here comes y question, what should I do with the technical state like "isMessageSenttoSystemA" somehow I have the feeling that this state does not belong to the aggregate itself but it is a side effect of the event.

Can I create a third table and bind it to the event where I can write my technical state? How am I supposed to name such table? I realy have difficulties finding a correct name ?

UPDATE: I am not sure if it becomes clear from the question.But I am mostly interested in how to model the data in the database. I use RDBMS.

UPDATE2: I don't want to implement Event sourcing, and I think this is not a prerequisite in order to have Event driven architecture.

Comment: What will you do with `isMessageSentToASystem`? Is there an overarching process or logic that requires that data, and if so, can you describe it?

Comment: For example the message can be  case in a CRM system. In this sense it will be isCaseCreatedinCRM for example. There can be two reasons we want this flag. 1) debugging in case that the overal flow has succeeded but the customer has reported missing case on the CRM side. 2) It can be used if we want to guaantee 100% that the service on the CRM side has actualy been invoked.

Answer (score 1):

The unmutated state AND mutating events belongs to the aggregate.

I strongly suggest you to download the code of Vaughn Vernon, he is the author of Implementing Domain Driven Design (IDDD) book.

Here is the class that contains answers to your questions:

https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_common/src/main/java/com/saasovation/common/domain/model/EventSourcedRootEntity.java

Notice the logic here and the relation with the EventStore, there is a list of mutating events, the events that are effectively changing your entity, and a pointer to the unmutated version. Those are used in the implementation of event store, check the MySQL implementation to understand.

https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_common/src/main/java/com/saasovation/common/port/adapter/persistence/eventsourcing/mysql/MySQLJDBCEventStore.java

On the loading side, all events from the event store are loaded and applied to the Event sourced root entity but not stored in the mutating event list. So the state of your entity is restored to the last version of your audit log, and any modifications are traced in memory in this list, which is flushed into the database when saved.

As for the structure of the event store itself, it is very straightforward:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_es_event_store` (
    `event_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `event_body` varchar(65000) NOT NULL,
    `event_type` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    `stream_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    `stream_version` int(11) NOT NULL,
    KEY (`stream_name`),
    UNIQUE KEY (`stream_name`, `stream_version`),
    PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: What if I don't want to have Event sourcing. I mean the Event sourcing is not mandatory technic to apply in order to have Event Driven architecture. Anyway thanks for the readings they are very interesting. You have +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

`isMessageSentToSystemA` is a query side service, you can check that constraint before dispatching command and changing the aggregate.
Also you can use SAGA to perform distributed transaction and manage workflow of your use-case

Comment: My question is where do the execution state belong, does it belong the the aggregate, or does it belong to the even that has triggered its generation/mutation.

Comment: Your aggregate state built from the history, and the history stores in eventStore that can be one table in RDBMS, other states or data belongs to read side and can be stored in any where. it is good to store read data as denormalized that means less usage of R part of RDBMS. BTW `isMessageSentToSystemA` does not belongs to the aggregate